# C program that reads in a text file and displays each line except for all blank lines and comments

Tags: c, tokenize

Basically, I need to read in a text file and only print full lines excluding anything that begins w/ a comment or whitespace. I'm having difficulty ignoring after the comments, or basically ignore whatever is after the `;` up until the `\n` char. Which would be indicating the end of the line.

I thought this code would work but it still prints after the comments,

```
 char* t=strtok(line,"\n ,.; ");
          while(t != NULL ) {
            if(t == ";"){
                t = strtok(NULL," ");
                while(t != NULL && t!="\n") {
                t = strtok(NULL, "");
              }
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%s\n",t);
                t = strtok( NULL, "\n ,.; \n");
            }
          }
        }
```

this is the full code:

```
int main()
{

char line [5000];
FILE *fp;

fp=fopen("gt.txt", "r");
if (fp == NULL)
 perror ("error opening file");
else{
  while(fgets (line, sizeof (line), fp)){
    char* t=strtok(line,"\n ,.; ");
      while(t != NULL ) {
        if(t == ";"){
            t = strtok(NULL," ");
            while(t != NULL && t!="\n") {
            t = strtok(NULL, "");
          }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%s\n",t);
            t = strtok( NULL, "\n ,.; \n");
        }
      }
    }
  }
fclose(fp);
return(0);
}
```

This is what I print and also what is used as my text file beneath:

```
hello                                                                                        
goodbye 
error                                                                                        
interesting                                                                                  
comment                                                                                      
wonderful
```

---

semicolons are real semicolons in the text file:

```
hello
goodbye


(semicolon) error
(semicolon) error

interesting (semicolon) comment

wonderful
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How you recognize comments?

Comment: a semicolon represents a comment

Comment: So, a semicolon starts a comment and a newline marks the end of the comment?  And there are no strings to worry about, so a line containing `a string "holding; a semicolon"` has a comment starting at the semicolon?  Quoting conventions for strings make life endlessly entertaining in comment strippers.  C is bad enough; shell is harder; Perl is … well, let's say Perl is a law unto itself (even though it only has `#` to introduce comments, it has lots and lots of ways of quoting things).

Answer (score 2):

> only print full lines excluding anything that begins (with) a comment or whitespace

OP's `if(t == ";"){` is not the needed function. [@Craig Estey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52865165/2410359).  Be sure to enable all warnings to save time.

That compares the pointer `char *t` to `";"` and likely OP wanted to compare the content of the strings pointed to or maybe compare if `*t` was a `';'`.

---

Sometimes a [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine#Example:_coin-operated_turnstile) is nice simple  approach.  Keep track of the end-of-line.  When starting a new line, `previous == '\n'`, test if it is a blank-able line.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define COMMENT_CHAR (';')

int main(void) {
  FILE *fp = fopen("gt.txt", "r");
  if (fp == NULL) {
    perror("error opening file");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  bool blank_the_line = false;
  int previous = '\n';
  int ch;

  while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
    if (previous == '\n') {
      blank_the_line = isspace(ch) || ch == COMMENT_CHAR;
    }
    if (!blank_the_line) {
      fputc(ch, stdout);
    }
    previous = ch;
  }

  fclose(fp);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Note: no line length limit.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `t == ";"` is [probably] invalid and won't even compile cleanly with `-Wall`:

```
orig.c: In function ‘main’:
orig.c:19:11: warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior [-Waddress]
     if (t == ";") {
           ^~
orig.c:21:28: warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior [-Waddress]
      while (t != NULL && t != "\n") {
                            ^~
```

`if (t == ";")` compares the address contained in `t` against the address of the string literal `";"`. This does *not* test the *content* of what `t` points to for equality with the string `";"` and will almost never produce the desired result.

The usual way to compare strings is to use `strcmp` et. al (e.g.) `if (strcmp(t,";") == 0)`. This compares the *content* pointed to by `t` with the string.

---

Assuming `;` is your comment character, adding that to the delimiter arg in the `strtok` call is incorrect because it will fail on partial lines that have *some* valid text and end in a trailing comment.

The comment *char* will be stripped but the returned token from `strtok` will no longer contain it. The returned token after the `;` will be the first token after it (i.e. the first token of the *comment*). But, we won't be able to detect this so we'll print the whole line--not what we want.

Thus, a separate scan for the comment char is needed to strip the comment char and subsequent text *before* looping with `strtok`

Here's a cleaned up version that should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(void)
{
    char line[5000];
    FILE *fp;
    char *cp;
    char *bp;
    char *sep;(i.e. we will strip the 

    fp = fopen("gt.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("error opening file");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)) {
        // strip comment from right side of line (do this _before_ token scan)
        cp = strchr(line,';');
        if (cp != NULL)
            *cp = 0;

        // set up for token scan
        bp = line;
        sep = "";

        // output all valid tokens on the line
        while (1) {
            // locate next token
            cp = strtok(bp," ,.\t\n");
            bp = NULL;

            // stop if didn't find one
            if (cp == NULL)
                break;

            // print the token
            printf("%s%s",sep,cp);

            // separate tokens by a space
            sep = " ";
        }

        // end line that had _valid_ data
        if (sep[0] != 0)
            printf("\n");
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "`t == ";"` is invalid [and won't even compile]" Why not?

Comment: @Swordfish I compiled with `-Wall` and it was flagged for unspecified behavior

Comment: Strange wording. Comparing two pointers should not be unspecified.

Comment: @Swordfish _Technically_, it's legal [so it's not an error]. It's complaining about comparing the address that `t` points to against the address of a _string literal_. This is not quite the same as comparing two pointers (e.g. `if (t == s)`) where such a shortcut could be valid: `char *t = ";"; char *s = ";"; if (t == s)`.  But, this is dicey at best. This _might_ match or it might _not_, particularly if `t` and `s` where defined in separate compilation units. Thus, `-Waddress` is flagging it as something that will almost always produce incorrect/undesired results.

Comment: Um. Yes. I know. I just wondered about the wording of the warning.

Comment: @Swordfish `clang` uses the `-Wstring-compare` warning. It produces a similar message but adds a suggestion to use `strncmp`

Comment: cl spits `warning C4130: '==': logical operation on address of string constant`

Comment: @Swordfish [Suprisingly], a better diagnostic message but, unfortunately, I don't do windows :-)

Comment: Yeah, it is a real shame the the clearly superiour compiler is not available to the many gnu/linux users there are.

Comment: @Swordfish Ouch :-)

Comment: Sowwy, really ;-)